# Python: Convert '3.5' to integer

Tags: python

So far, I would do `int(float('3.5'))`

Any other good way to do?

Note: 3.5 is a string.

I want to use the the built-in API that specify for this sort of problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track, and the best solution is probably as mentioned:

```
>>> int(float("3.5"))
```

This truncates the float.

If you want a different type of rounding, you can use the [`math`](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html) package:

```
>>> import math
>>> x = "3.5"
>>> math.floor(float(x)) # returns FP; still needs to be wrapped in int()
3.0
>>> math.ceil(float(x)) # same
4.0
>>> math.trunc(float(x)) # returns an int; essentially the same as int(float(x))
3
```

If on the other hand you wish to round the number to the nearest integer, you may use the floating-point built-in operation [`round`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#round) before converting to an integer, e.g.

```
>>> int(round(float(x))) # 3.5 => 4
4
>>> int(round(3.4999))
3
```

Answer (score 4):

The only code which could possibly be simpler and clearer than what you have is `int('3.5')`, which doesn't work.  Therefore, what you have is the simplest, clearest working code.

Answer (score 1):

All that you need is
`int(3.5)`

Note that this truncates; it doesn't round.

Comment: >>> int('3.5')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/apache2/2.2/htdocs/try.py", line 146, in wrapper
    value, wantmore = evaluate(source, hisvars)
  File "/var/apache2/2.2/htdocs/try.py", line 126, in evaluate
    value = eval(code, hisvars)
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3.5'
>>>

Comment: Actually it doesn't -- in that case I'd use the method in your post.  Otherwise you get `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3.5'`

Comment: @Ramy: It should not "work" when the arg is a string, and fortunately it doesn't. Please note that the question is tagged 'python', not 'awk'.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `int(eval('3.5'))`

Comment: I would say this is a bad idea, as generally eval can be rather ugly. If there are options other than eval, then they should probably be considered first.